# CRMint - Rate limit for writes exceeded when patching using GAAudiencesUpdater

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-remarketing-audience

I am using the GAAudiencesUpdater to update audiences. The GAAudiencesUpdater seems to handle the creation of the audiences the first time fine, however, when the pipeline runs on subsequent days and uses the patch method the job fails every time. I am well within the Google Analytics API quota limits which is 50 writes per day for these types of jobs so I'm unclear as to why there is a rate limit for writes exceeded error.

The error I'm getting is: Unexpected error: HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/xxx/webproperties/UA-xxx-17/remarketingAudiences/xxx?alt=json returned "Quota Error: Rate limit for writes exceeded.">

Screenshot from the CRMint UI attached.
[image]

Would appreciate any guidance on why this may be the case with the patch method specifically? Thanks!

Comment: this means that you are hitting a limit of usage for Analytics, you need to reach [Analytics support](https://support.google.com/analytics/gethelp) they can help you to determine the root cause or if you need they can help you with a quota increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the CRMint retry logic. Fortunately one of the contributors to the CRMint project resolved that [bug](https://github.com/google/crmint/pull/204) and this isn't a concern any longer when updating audiences in CRMint.